# Implementing a simple queue using array

Tags: c, queue

I tried debugging this small little code; i am a beginner and am struggling to figure out why my rear value is not incrementing. It gets re-initialized to 0 in the else part. I want to store the consecutive elements in the queue but i am not able to.
Thanks in advance
I have added the output of code down at the end.

This is the initial declaration and the enqueue function

```
//queue implementation using arrays
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 5

int Queue[size];
int rear =-1;
int front =-1;

void enqueue(int value){
    if(rear == size-1){
        printf("\nOVERFLOW CONDITION\n");
    }
    else  if(rear=-1 && front ==-1){
        front = 0;
        rear = 0;
        Queue[rear]=value;
        printf("ELSE IF\n");
        printf("Rear val after:%d\n\n",rear);
    }
    else{
        printf("Rear val before:%d\n",rear );
        printf("ELSE\n");
        rear++;
        printf("Rear val after:%d\n",rear );
        Queue[rear]= value;
        printf("Rear val at end of else:%d\n\n",rear );
    }
```

This is the main function:

```
int main(){

    enqueue(4);
    enqueue(2);
    enqueue(33);

    return 0;   
}
```

My output:

```
ELSE IF
Rear val after:0

Rear val before:0
ELSE
Rear val after:1
Rear val at end of else: =1

Rear val before:0
ELSE
Rear val after:1
Rear val at end of else: =1


--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.01729 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `if(rear=-1 && front ==-1)` -> `if(rear==-1 && front ==-1)`

Comment: Isnt this the same thing?

Comment: Look more closely: `=` vs `==`

Comment: hint: usually good practice is to use capital letters with #define - #define SIZE 5

Answer (score 0):

You have missed one '=' in the else if condition while comparing the rear value.

```
if(rear=-1 && front==-1)
```

Should be

```
if(rear==-1 && front==-1)
```